# No display out or signal, is the Pi 4 faulty?

Tags: hdmi

first time posting, but I'm just confused, and wondering if I got a faulty raspberry pi 4. I have a raspberry pi 4 8Gb RAM Model.

Parts used for the pi:

-ice tower cooler

-2 Cana kit micro HDMI to HDMI cables

-Samsung Evo select 32gb micro SD U1

-SanDisk 32 GB micro SD HC class 10

-Team Group 64Gb micro SD XC card U1 Class 10

-have wireless keyboard and mouse ready to use

-4 displays: 2 TVs, PC monitor, 3.5 inch display specifically for raspberry pi.

What I tried:

-swapping the SD cards

-reformatting cards

-changing the config.txt files as stated as solutions in youtube videos and other sites. (Like adding the HDMI safe mode default, boosting output to 4, force and group HDMI; other combination was just hdmi_force_hotplug and config_hdmi_boost to 9.)

-swapped display cables since the Cana kit came with 2 cables.

My TV (TCL Roku TV 1080p 60Hz) does not display anything, at boot up of like 3 seconds the screen goes from the red (this is the standard background of my tv because it's a TCL Roku tv) to black screen for about 1-2 seconds then back to standard red where its waiting for a connection where it says no signal.

My PC monitor (Samsung Odyssey G7) has its black screen with background light flashing on and off once every 2-3 seconds and like every 10-15 seconds I get a weird picture for a split second as well, here is the photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MriqR.jpg

Other TV does what my roku TV does, where it changes color for a second and then states that it is an unsupported signal (it is a Sony Bravia 55 inch from like 2015).

The last display is the one specifically made for the raspberry pi from GeeekPi and that just after 5 seconds of powering up just black stripes go from top to bottom then nothing and just a thin black stripe horizontally in the middle.

Any help is appreciated, this is my first raspberry pi so if I did something a newbie does, I apologize. I have been on the internet for about 2 hours yesterday and another hour today looking for a solution and nothing.

Comment: you didn't mention which operating system image you are using - also, first boot can take a while, did you give it a couple of minutes

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by connecting just one monitor, in the HDMI port near to the USB-C, with no SD card or USB connected.
You should see something like this:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/images/bootloader-diagnostics.png

If you see this screen, at first it won't be hardware.

Let's do the 2nd step: check that your drive is not corrupted and the operating system starts. Add an empty file with the name "ssh" to the root of your microSD, with Raspberry OS on it, and an ethernet cable connected.

In a computer with Linux/Windows do `ssh pi@IP_of_your_RaspberryPi` and check if you can log in. If you can your OS it's healthy, and you can use even activate later VNC to change the monitor's resolution without taking the SD card all the time, and try to find a compatible resolution with your monitors.